# Google Analytics query,retrieve all pages visited by a user during a session

Tags: php, google-analytics

i need to retrieve data from google analytic using the API in the following format:

```
Date & time              Source       Page      Length
============================================================
7 Sep 2016 1:02 am       google       2         3 min 54 sec
------------------------------------------------------------
google / organic
http://www.example.com/page-1            1 min 4 sec
http://www.example.com/page-2            2 min 0 sec
http://www.example.com/page-3            0 min 50 sec
```

any advise ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, that out of the box API capabilities do not allow to get user level data through reporting API.

> After processing, session data for which userId was set is available
>   for User ID-enabled views (profiles) in Cross-Device reports. Although
>   the session data is available via the Core Reporting API, the userId
>   field is not available as a dimension in reports and can not be
>   exported from Analytics.

Please refer to [this article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205850?hl=en&ref_topic=3123660#reporting) for further details.

It could be a workaround to use one of custom dimensions as a sort of user ID, and use that dimension to report user level data. Please note, that such ID cannot be any personal data in terms of Analytics ToC, and I haven't checked, if such usage of custom variables would be in line with Analytics ToC.